# Variable Declaration & Memory Allocation

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know whether memory is allocated during the local variable declaration process.

Suppose I write this code inside function, **int a =10;** memory is allocated and the value 10 is stored in that.

What about **int a;** ? This declaration statement will it allocate 4 bytes of memory?

Thanks.

Comment: I imagine so, since at that point `a` has a valid value of `0`.

Comment: Yep declaring a variable allocates space for it till it goes out of scope and is garbage collected. Structs like your example will have a default value, where as reference types will be declared as null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory Allocation for Variable Declared in Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343564/memory-allocation-for-variable-declared-in-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are usually stored on stack, so indeed bytes are allocated for `int`:

```
int a;
```

Because it simply uses default value (0), so it is the same as:

```
int a = 0;
```

`int` is a value type, so on stack is stored its value. If you would create local variable with reference type:

```
SomeClass a;
```

Then on stack it would be allocated only *reference* (with value null, as it is default value for reference types). For more information you can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727266/stack-and-heap-in-c-sharp)

Comment: So you are telling like by default it takes 0 as its value.
Suppose I write
int a;
int b=a; we will get an error like "use of unassigned local variable a".  In this case why its not taking the default value 0?

Comment: `a` must have some value from **runtime** perspective (default 0), but **compiler** treats this as an error if you are using value without implicitly assigned value.

Comment: And one should mention that the compiler usually gets rid of unused local variables... so if you just write int a; and never read its value, it will just be erased and not even cost you space on the stack

Answer (score 2):

When you call a method, space for each local variable is allocated on the stack.

So if you declare an `int` variable in a method, it's stack frame will take up an extra 4 bytes of memory.

No additional memory is used anywhere else, and it is cleaned up when the method returns.

Something important to understand here is that MSIL does not support declaring a property just anywhere in a method. Whenever you declare a variable in C#, the declaration is moved to the method header in the compiled bytecode. Every variable is allocated when the method is called.